# LNK2020 sÝmbolo (token) sin resolver (06000006) AStack::.ctor [C++/CLI]

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'am getting this error when I try to compile, any idea what is happening? I think it is something related to the integers maxSize and top. When I try to change them to something like "int^ maxSize" I can't use those ints to manage the array positions. Thank you very much!

AStack.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Carta.h"
#define defaultSize 2048

ref class AStack
{
private:
    int maxSize;
    int top;
    array< Carta^ >^ ListArray; //puntero a arreglo

public:
    AStack();
    AStack(int size) {
        maxSize = size;
        top = 0;
        ListArray = gcnew array< Carta^ >(size);
    }

    ~AStack() { delete[] ListArray; }

    void clear() { top = 0; }

    void push(Carta^ pElement) {
        if (top == maxSize) {
            Console::WriteLine("Stack is full");
        }
        ListArray[top++] = pElement;
    }

    Carta^ pop() {
        if (top == 0) {
            Console::WriteLine("Stack empty");
        }
        return ListArray[--top]; //retorna top y despues lo decrementa
    }

    Carta^ topValue() {
        if (top == 0) {
            Console::WriteLine("Stack empty");
        }
        return ListArray[top - 1];
    }

    int length() {
        return top; //largo de pila
    }
};
```

Carta.h

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;

ref class Carta
{

private:
    String^ cara;
    String^ palo;
    String^ direccion;

public:
    Carta();
    Carta(String^ pCara, String^ pPalo) {
        cara = pCara;
        palo = pPalo;
        direccion = pCara + pPalo;
    }

    String^ print() {
        return (cara + " de " + palo);
    }

    String^ getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }
};
```

Deck.h

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Carta.h"
#include "AStack.h"

#define ARRAY_SIZE 54

using namespace System;

ref class Deck
{
private:
    array< Carta^ >^ deck = gcnew array< Carta^ >(ARRAY_SIZE);
    int posicion;
    bool ya;

public:
    Deck() {
        ya = false;
        array<String^>^ caras = { "As","Dos","Tres","Cuatro","Cinco","Seis","Siete","Ocho","Nueve","Diez",
            "Jack","Dama","Rey" };

        array<String^>^ palos = { "Corazon","Diamante","Espada","Trebol" };

        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE - 2; i++) {
            deck[i] = gcnew Carta(caras[i % 13], palos[i / 13]);
        }
        deck[52] = gcnew Carta("Joker", "Negro");
        deck[53] = gcnew Carta("Joker", "Rojo");
    }

    ~Deck() {
        delete[]deck;
    }

    void mostrar() {
        for (int i = 0; i<54; i++) {
            Console::WriteLine(deck[i]->print());           
        }
    }

    void mezclar() {
        for (int primero = 0; primero < 54; primero++) {
            int segundo = (rand() + time(0)) % 54;
            Carta^ temp = deck[primero];
            deck[primero] = deck[segundo];
            deck[segundo] = temp;
        }
    }

    Carta^ topCarta() {
        return deck[0];
    }


    void cortar(int pos) {
        if (pos != 0 && pos != 53) {
            AStack^ pila;

            for (int i = pos; i < 54; i++) {
                pila->push(deck[i]);
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < pos; j++) {
                pila->push(deck[j]);
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < 54; k++) {
                deck[k] = pila->pop();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `AStack` and `Carta` 's default constructors have no bodies, unless they're in some other place you're not showing.

Comment: Please abstain from tagging C++/CLI as C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Simple Answer

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use the .Net Library class [System::Collections::Generic::Stack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx?cs-lang=cpp).

## The More Complicated Answer

```
AStack();
```

This is almost certainly the cause of your error: You've declared a no-parameters constructor, but never implemented it.

```
Carta();
```

Same thing here.

```
~AStack() { delete[] ListArray; }
```

This is wrong: `delete[]` is for things allocated with `new`. Things allocated with `gcnew` don't need a `delete[]`. (You do use `delete`, without the `[]`, to [Dispose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) objects, but array isn't an [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx?cs-lang=cpp).)

Comment: You have all the reason!, Thank you very much :)